# Deploying Apache Solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, nginx

I've been experimenting with Apache SOLR and I'm ready to integrate it with a rails application. However, I'd like to make sure I know how to deploy solr. I currently have the rails application deployed using passenger+nginx. Is it possible to deploy SOLR using nginx as well? If so, how would I do that? Otherwise, what is the preferred method of deployment? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr needs to run in a Java EE application server. You can use [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) or [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/). Nginx will  act as a proxy via [AJP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_JServ_Protocol) or something simliar to forward all RESTless request to Solr. I haven't used my ajp with nginx but I have read about [this](http://code.google.com/p/nginx-ajp-module/). Essentially you will have a Java EE application server, Rails server, nginx, passenger and ajp proxy running all at the same time.

You can also setup a proxy pass and there is a [tutorial here](http://sacharya.com/nginx-proxy-to-jetty-for-java-apps/). Explore different options to see which one is bet for you.

Comment: Thank you =) I just got deployed solr!